# How to copy a string into a dynamical two-dimensional array?

Tags: c

I have to copy the resulting strings from the streaming input to the strings of my two-dimensional array. Is it possible to do this at all and what is wrong in my code?

The task is to getchar() strings and put them in two-dimensional array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *arr = NULL;
    char string[50];
    char sym;

    int counter = 0;
    int counter_str = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while((sym = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if((sym != ' ') && (sym != ('\t') && (sym != '\n'))){
            string[counter] = sym;
            counter += 1;
            }
            
        if(sym == '\n'){
            string[counter] = sym;
            counter += 1;
            counter_str += 1;
            string[counter] = '\0';
            
            arr = (char*) realloc(arr, counter_str * sizeof(char));
            arr[counter_str - 1] = malloc(1 + strlen(string));
            strcpy(arr[counter_str - 1], string);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the mallolc / strcpy can be replaced by strdup. getchar returns an int not a char, you need `int sym`

Comment: I think you'd want `realloc(arr, counter_str * sizeof(char *))` to hold enough space for the string pointer.

Comment: Where is 2D array here?

Comment: Possible *UB* without `if(counter < sizeof string - 2) { /* rest of your code inside while */ } else { /* add char, nul-terminate and copy partial line */ }`  Always protect your array-bounds...

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use a 2D array in this case. Use a 1D array of char pointers.

Answer (score 1):

1. `char *arr` is a pointer to a char and not the 2d array you had in mind.
2. `getchar()` returns an int and `EOF` is usually defined as `-1`.  It is implementation defined if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 50

int main() {
    char **arr = NULL;
    char string[STR_LEN];
    int counter = 0;
    int counter_str = 0;
    for(; counter + 1 < STR_LEN;) {
        int sym = getchar();
        if(sym == EOF)
            break;
        if(sym != ' ' && sym != '\t')
            string[counter++] = sym;
        if(sym == '\n') {
            string[counter] = '\0';
            char **tmp = realloc(arr, (counter_str + 1) * sizeof(*arr));
            if(!tmp) {
                printf("realloc failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            arr = tmp;
            arr[counter_str] = strdup(string);
            if(!arr[counter_str]) {
                printf("strdup failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            counter = 0;
            counter_str++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < counter_str; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

and example run:

```
hello world
again
helloworld
again
```

Unless you are super concerned about fitting as many non-space and non-tab characters it might be clearer to just read then strip the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 50

void strip(char *s, const char *accept) {
    for(;;) {
        s = strpbrk(s, accept);
        if(!s)
            break;
        *s = s[1];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char **arr = NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0;; i++) {
        char **tmp = realloc(arr, (i + 1) * sizeof(*arr));
        if(!tmp) {
            printf("realloc failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        arr = tmp;
        arr[i] = malloc(STR_LEN);
        if(!arr[i]) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(!fgets(arr[i], STR_LEN, stdin)) {
            free(arr[i]);
            arr[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        strip(arr[i], " \t");
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Especially if you can bound the number of strings (`N`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3
#define STR_LEN 50

void strip(char *s, const char *accept) {
    for(;;) {
        s = strpbrk(s, accept);
        if(!s)
            break;
        *s = s[1];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char arr[N][STR_LEN];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(!fgets(arr[i], STR_LEN, stdin))
            break;
        strip(arr[i], " \t");
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; *arr[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
    }
}
```